# PHP Wordpress Woocommerce Get Product Name By ID

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to get the Woocommerce product name by ID using PHP. Here's what I've tried so far but so far, no dice.

```
require_once('../wp-load.php');

var_dump(wc_get_product('284') );
var_dump(get_the_title('284') );
```

Have also just tried this:

```
$product = wc_get_product(284);
var_dump($product->get_title() );
```

All attempts product no output.

Here's the code I'm using to get the IDs in the first place:

```
function getProdIds($userId){
    $prodResults = [];
    $subscriptions = wcs_get_users_subscriptions( $userId );
        foreach ($subscriptions as $subKey => $sub){
            $subscription = wc_get_order($subKey);
            foreach( $subscription->get_items() as $item_id => $product_subscription ){
                // Get the name
                $prodResults[] = $product_subscription->get_product_id();
            }
        }
        return $prodResults;
}
```

Comment: I've tried with the product ID as both string and int.

Comment: (If that is not what you meant by “no output”, then explain what else.)

Comment: I believe I have all error reporting on

Comment: Updated to show where the IDs are coming from.

Comment: @CBroe That was not the issue. Please undo that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this below

```
$product = wc_get_product( '284' );

$productname= $product->get_title();

ELSE 
global $product;  
$id= '284';
$productname = get_the_title($id);
```

Comment: Both produced no output.

Comment: Hi @xendi second one is working fine.

Comment: Working for you? I don't understand. I ran that by itself. Maybe not good to run from CLI mode? One moment...

Comment: Hi @xendi review below screen url
https://ibb.co/im2VpT

Comment: I was testing via CLI. That was the problem. Your example works. Thank you.

Comment: would you happen to know how I might get such code to work via CLI?